# Golang: Unkown column in 'where clause'

Tags: sql, go

I'm writing unit tests and came across Error 1054: Unknown column 'TestUpdateRule2' in 'where clause'. The error happens in the cleanUp function. I have been using this cleanUp function to "clean up" after other unit tests for other CRUD operations, but for some reason the Update function is failing.

My Rule struct:

```
    RuleNo      int64       `json:"ruleNo" db:"rule_no"`
    Category    string      `json:"category" db:"category"`
    Identifier  string      `json:"identifier" db:"identifier"`
    Operator    string      `json:"operator" db:"operator"`
    Value       string      `json:"value" db:"rule_value"`
    ProductId   string      `json:"productId" db:"product_id"`
    ServiceCode string      `json:"serviceCode" db:"service_code"`
    TemplateNo  int         `json:"templateNo" db:"template_no"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time   `json:"createdAt" db:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time   `json:"updatedAt" db:"updated_at"`
}
```

The cleanup Function:

```
func cleanUp(t *testing.T, connection *sqlx.DB, table string, column string, value string) {
    query := fmt.Sprintf("DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s = %s", table, column, value)

    _, err := connection.Exec(query, table, column, value)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }
}
```

```
func TestUpdateRule(t *testing.T) {
    repo := setUp(t)
    defer repo.Database.Close()

    connection := repo.Database.Connection(context.Background())

    dt := time.Now()

    cleanUp(t, connection, "rat_rule", "product_id", "TestUpdateRule2")

    // Create a rule
    query := `INSERT INTO rat_rule (category, identifier, operator, rule_value, product_id, service_code, template_no, created_at, updated_at) 
              VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

    result, err := connection.Exec(query, "TestUpdateRule", "TestUpdateRule", "TestUpdateRule", "TestUpdateRule", "TestUpdateRule", "TestUpdateRule", 4, dt, dt)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }

    addedRuleNo, err := result.LastInsertId()
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }

    ruleToUpdate := rule.Rule{
        RuleNo: addedRuleNo,
        Category: "TestUpdateRule2",
        Identifier: "TestUpdateRule2",
        Operator: "TestUpdateRule2",
        Value: "TestUpdateRule2",
        ProductId: "TestUpdateRule2",
        ServiceCode: "TestUpdateRule2",
        TemplateNo: 4,
        CreatedAt: dt,
        UpdatedAt: time.Now(),
    }

    // Update the rule created above
    affectedRows, err := repo.UpdateRule(context.Background(), ruleToUpdate)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }

    assert.Equal(t, 1, affectedRows, "The number of affected rows should be 1")
}
```

Comment: You're using `Exec` in `cleanUp` as if this were a prepared statement with query params, but it's not. You're passing in a static query, I don't see why you're passing table/column/value to `Exec`.

Comment: You should also try adding a `fmt.Println(query)` to `cleanUp` to see exactly what query is being produced, just to make sure it's correct.

Comment: This is the query, which is correct: DELETE FROM rat_rule WHERE product_id = TestUpdateRule2

Comment: Figured it out, I can pass the strings in for the database table/column name, but the actual values must have the ? instead of %s.